# Что лучше redirecr или error 404 когда нужный язык не найден

Tags: cms, seo, header

Стал вопрос, что делать когда в базе языков для сайта нет языка который запрашивает пользователь?

1. Делать специальный redirect и сразу становиться вопрос какой и куда:
   на страницу с авто-определением языка; на страницу выбора языка, но такой может не быть.
2. Показывать страницу ошибки 501, 523 или 400, 405, 412, 404.
3. Или есть уже готовое и проверенное решение на которое корректно реагируют поисковые системы и адекватно на это реагируют.
4. Свой вариант ))))

Comment: вероятно, вопросы по сео лучше задавать на htpps://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Alex вероятно, но тут тоже задают вопросы по сео и я хочу получить ответ на русском языке, а не на английском.

Answer (score 0):

1. Это вариант, конечно, но не очень хороший. Вы умышленно будете перенаправлять пользователя, тем самым ставить его в затруднительное положение. В результате, скорее всего, пользователь уйдет искать информацию на нужном ему языке.
2. Не рекомендовал бы. Вообще уйдет посетитель. Лучше показывать информационную страницу, типа "Сорри, текущая языковая версия сайта не найдена, предлагаем вам выбрать более подходящий вариант:" и варианты версий (англ. нем. русс. франц. И еще что там есть). Такая страница будет иметь ответ сервера 200 Ок, но ее можно закрыть от индексации в файле robots.txt или оформить мета тег robots noindex follow (страница не индексируется, но по ссылкам робот поисковой системы будет переходить).
3. Если речь идет о Google, то они рекомендуют использовать атрибут hreflang для указания языка или регионального URL.
4. Если запросов действительно много 10-30%  от общего количества (много мало это все в аналитике нужно смотреть), то нужно делать языковую версию. Начать с главной, основных разделов и страниц, которые приносят максимальное количество трафика или продаж. Таким образом можно собирать доп. трафик. или доп. конверсии. Если мало, то создание такой версии может быть нерентабельным делом.

Comment: По второму варианту мы не можем дать 200ОК по хорошему, и у вас второй вариант плавно перелазит в первый, а там редирект на страницу выбора языков. И тут опять приходим к вопросу, какой редирект которая выведет уже 200ОК или все же выводить спец страницу типа упс языка нет, но не с заголовком 200, потому что страницы то такой нет, и тут нужен какой-то подходящий заголовок 400 405 412 или 404.

Comment: В моем ответе
1 вариант – если редирект то 301
2 вариант – инфо стр со ссылками на языковые версии (без редиректа). Это точно такая же страница как и все ваши обычные ("О нас" , "Доставка"). Только она будет закрыта от индексации, и не доступна в навигационном меню.
Она даст понять пользователю, что не так. И резко не перенаправлять его на другую страницы, не давая объяснений.

Comment: Если все же создавать страницу 4xx, то ответ сервера должен быть 404.
Но в таком случае у вас будет два типа 404 страниц: 
- запрашиваемая страница не найдена, выберете интересующий, более подходящий раздел (стандартная 404 страница)
- запрашиваемая языковая версия не найдена, выберете другой язык

Или создать одну 404 страницу с ответом сервера 404, которая будет перекрывать вышеупомянутые страницы.

Comment: Хотел бы дополнить ваш ответ видео "What should I do with old 404 errors?": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbjYkpdjorA